# ios How to put custom controller redirect obj-c code in custom view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xib

I am new to ios app development and also with objective-c coding. I don't know whether it is possible. First let me describe what I have done and then I will describe what I want. I have added screen shot below you can view that directly or read the description first then look at the screenshot.

So, I have created a custom xib attached with custom view. I named it as Menu.h and .c

I have put four buttons there each of which are created IBOutlet in that Custom view as well. They are now created in run time. I had to set few properties for a controller in storyboard under "user defiend run time attributes" settings. I am able to get that value in custom view using awakeFromNib function. With that Now I can access and change properties of those buttons easily. I can also put actions to those buttons with this code

```
[btnOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And into that I am gettings my action.

**But what I am trying to do is to be able to use the controller redirect code like following**

```
      NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
     UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
     ViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
     [ViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

It is working normally in a controller but now when I try to put that in custom view into that button action it shows me error "no visible interface for 'Menu' declared the selector...". I have added the screenshot below.

[no visible interface for 'Menu' declared the selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yT915.png)

Please suggest What I can do to resolve this? It is making me nuts. :)

Comment: `presentViewController` method is only declared for `UIViewController` subclasses. It seems that your `Menu` class doesn't inherit from `UIViewController`

Comment: Which is the super class of your custom class?

Comment: Yes you are right redent84. It is UIView Payal Maniyar

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use segues when you use storyboards. Add one in IB from a view controller (push) to another view controller and invoke performSegue method:

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"MySegue" sender: self];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in an UIViewController Subclass.

From an architectural point of view don't do Code like that in a View Class instead use a ViewController (hence the availability of such methods only in UIViewController subclasses)

In your Storyboard create a segue with an unique identifier like for example "ViewControllerSegue" and then call

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerSegue"];
```

And setUp your ViewController in

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
             sender:(id)sender;
```